# WebSocket is Null after onOpen

Tags: javascript, websocket

I try to use the following code to connect a Websocket:

```
var sConn = {
    socket: null,
    uri: "ws://" + window.location.host + "/socket/",

    init: function() { 
        this.socket = new WebSocket(this.uri);
        this.socket.onopen = this.onOpen;
        this.socket.onclose = this.onClose;
        this.socket.onerror = this.onError;
        this.socket.onmessage = this.onMessage;
    },


    onOpen: function(){
        console.log(this.socket); // prints "undefined"
        this.socket.send("Hello Server!"); // can't read property send of undefined
    },
    onClose: function(event){
         console.log("Close:",event); // is never called
    },
    onError: function(err){
        console.log("Error:",err); // also never called
    },
    onMessage: function(msg){
        console.log("Got Message:",msg);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    sConn.init();
});
```

unfortunately when onOpen is called socket seems to be undefined. I first thought maybe the socket is closed right after onOpen, but onClose is never called and onError is also never called.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing the binding context in `init()`.

Try rewriting it to this:

```
init: function() { 
  this.socket = new WebSocket(this.uri);
  this.socket.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
  this.socket.onclose = this.onClose.bind(this);
  this.socket.onerror = this.onError.bind(this);
  this.socket.onmessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
}
```

This makes sure that all the event handler functions in `sConn` are run with the correct `this` context.

Alternatively, you can refer to the socket with `sConn.socket` instead of `this.socket`.